# Error in ':' using C# and XML(XDocument)

Tags: c#, xml

I was trying something and ran into a problem using xml XDocument on C# and couldn't think of an effective way around it.

```
private void fillItems(string URL)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
        XDocument reader = XDocument.Parse(result);

        items.Clear();

        foreach (var item in reader.Descendants("item"))
        {
            xmlItem temp = new xmlItem(item.Element("title").Value, (item.Element("torrent:magnetURI") != null ? item.Element("torrent:magnetURI").Value:"(no uri)"));
            items.Add(temp);
        }
        updateList();
    }
```

The "torrent:magnetURI" gives a problem stating that the ':' is not allowed (in runtime), I can't do away with the ':' in the full result string as some data gets lost...

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated
the input url being used is "http://kickass.so/anime/?rss=1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torrent:` is a namespace. You have to use namespace when querying your data:

```
var torrent = XNamespace.Get("YourNamespaceUrl");

foreach (var item in reader.Descendants("item"))
{
    xmlItem temp = new xmlItem(item.Element("title").Value,
                       (item.Element(torrent + "magnetURI") != null
                            ? item.Element(torrent + "magnetURI").Value
                            : "(no uri)"));
    items.Add(temp);
}
```

Also, you can replace your conditional statement with `??` and `(string)XElement` case:

```
    xmlItem temp = new xmlItem(item.Element("title").Value,
                       ((string)item.Element(torrent + "magnetURI") ?? "(no uri)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the way you have it coded, I have a [public XML library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) that uses that syntax. But it also makes it simpler, because it takes a default value if the element doesn't exist.

```
foreach (var item in reader.Descendants("item"))
{
    xmlItem temp = new xmlItem(item.Element("title").Value, 
                               item.Get("torrent:magnetURI", "(no uri)"));
    items.Add(temp);
}
```

It figures out the `torrent` namespace for you by using internally:

```
XNamespace torrent = item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("torrent");
```